# Random whitespace in a PHP page (the client received page, but not the client-received source-code), but only when I use an include()

Tags: php, php-include

Ok, I am having the weirdest problem in history. I am making a website that works perfectly in HTML, but is having some REALLY odd behaviour when rendered from PHP - despite having the EXACT SAME client source code (I literally went through it character by character).

At first I thought I'd messed up something in my 'functions.php' file that I'm including, but I don't get any errors, and when I copy&paste the contents of that file into the place where the include('functions.php'); line is, the problem disappears.

Here's my code (with some HTML removed, this is all of the PHP):

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','1');
    include 'functions.php';
    $footer = file_get_contents('footer.txt');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Removed</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-custom.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent">
        <div id="logo">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
<?php
    echo trim(GetNav());
?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
<?php
    $NumberOfNewsItems = 2;
    echo trim(GetNews($NumberOfNewsItems));
?>
    </div>
<?php
    echo trim($footer);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The functions GetNav and GetNews grab info from the database so I'm not going to show the code from them, plus, as I mentioned earlier, if I don't include the file but instead copy it's contents to the place I make the include call then most of the whitespace disappears (there's still some where the 'echo $footer' call is.

Basically, when you look at the source code, everything looks fine. Where stuff gets incredibly strange is when you hit F12 to look at the dev tools and the elements tab shows a whole bunch of extra whitespace (surrounded by double quotes) immediately after the  tag (which impacts the look of the site) as well as between the footer and content Divs (which again, impacts the look of the site).

Also in this view, all of the tags from the  are below the first set of white-space and the  tag is empty (eg: `<head></head>`).

The source code looks fine (and if I copy and paste the source code into a HTML file it works flawlessly) and I have to admit that this has me tearing my hair out.

Please help me Obi-Wan-Kenobi, you're my only hope (yes, I love Star Wars, although I wish they'd made more than three movies).

P.S. This might be mega-obvious, but I'm a .Net developer doing this for a family member in my spare time (also it's fun to learn new languages, even ones overly fond of the $ sign), so apologies in advance if I'm the world's biggest newb.

EDIT: What I see in the dev tools is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
"



      "
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Removed</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-custom.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
```

Etc.

EDIT2: Just to be clear, I don't care what the dev tools show, it's just that I'm getting whitespace showing where those quotes are on the actual website, other than that everything is perfect.

EDIT3: Also, the whitespace cannot be clicked on with the element selector and selecting the whitespace in the element tab does not highlight anything on the website. Deleting it in the element tab however DOES fix the website (until it is reloaded obviously), but obviously doesn't help me with my problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you think look "wrong"? It's a bit hard to grasp from the text.

Comment: How did you inspect the source code? AFAIK Firefox shows you tidied HTML in "view source", so that might not exactly be what you received from the server. If the inclusion of `function.php` makes a difference, you should show this file too.

Comment: What I see in the dev tools is:
" " (but with several line-breaks between the quotes) and the meta, title, script and link tags from the head section appearing in the body tag instead.
The source code I was inspecting with View Source (in IE10, FF and Chrome, same results each time)

Comment: @Hank I updated the OP with what I see with the dev tools (Elements tab in Chrome).

Comment: @fab The functions inside function.php actually work perfectly (eg: GetNav and GetNews both output perfect html and those sections display correctly). It's other areas where the problems occur, but only when functions.php is a separate file.

Comment: What you show from that indicates there is some mismatched html somewhere, since you have your meta/script/link tags outside of head all of a sudden. The whitespace is probably, as @Akdr suggested from whitespace after the ?> in functions.php

Comment: @hank There is no whitespace after the ?> in functions.php and even if there were, that wouldn't change the page at all (no matter how much whitespace you have, what's shown on the website is just a single space). The html tags are not mis-matched in the source code of the PHP file (as you can see above) nor in the final source code that is sent to the user (in fact to be sure I replaced the function calls with:     echo "";
and the problems I'm having didn't go away (but the content generated by those functions obviously did).

Comment: Also, to explain what's happening on the website more: there's a large gap above the header div (which should be at the very top of the screen and is in the html version of the site) and a smaller (but still annoying) gap below the content div.

Comment: This is not going anywhere. Please post the complete generated html in a fiddle or something.

Comment: @hank If it wasn't clear by this point, copy and pasting the entire generated source code works PERFECTLY. I'll try copying the code from chrome and see if that works, I've looked through it and it looked ok though. FF and IE I've already copy-pasted the generated code into a new file and had it work perfectly.

Comment: EDIT: Ignore my answer, I just accidentally loaded the copy-pasted .html page instead of the .php page :(. Still having the same problems...

Comment: use require_once instead of include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix this in a way that satisfies me, but here's the workaround that I implemented:

I removed the include from the header entirely and broke up functions.php into one file per function and just included them where they needed to be called.

This alleviated my problem, although it's not ideal. Glad I don't have to use PHP on a daily basis :).

Comment: just use require_once instead of include

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ?> in your functions.php file and no blank rows after the code. And is the functions.php in the same directory as the main file?

And just a tip, include a footer.php instead of file_get_content :-)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but this did not help. Yes, functions.php is in the same directory - it's loaded successfully and all code executes properly. As I mentioned, having the EXACT SAME code inside the index.php file alleviates the problem.

Also, why use include instead of file_get_content for a pure html file?

Comment: Hm, sorry cant help you then. I googled file_get_content vs include and file_get_content is faster, my bad! But i learned something! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, on the console the source of the html looked like :

By checking the encoding some files were encoded with utf-8 with bom and some with big5. By saving those file to utf-8 ( without bom) solved the issue for me.

I have used Sublime Text 2 with the EncodingHelper from the package manager to see the current file encoding.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll check the encoding again, but I've been using Notepad++ and the encoding is set to utf-8 (without BOM) already (this was one of the first things I actually checked).

I kinda hope that np++ just hasn't overwritten some previous encoding and that changing this fixes everything perfectly :).